# Persisting the State to the Local Storage with Redux and Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm following [the tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) of Dan Abramov. However, I confusing at step add `persistedState` to `createStore`

My code like this:

```
const persistedState = loadState();

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
)

store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
  saveState({
    authReducer: store.getState().authpage
  })
}, 1000));
```

How can I pass `persistedState` to `createStore` with `redux-saga` middleware.

My reducer:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
[authpageContext]: authReducer,
  [profilepageContext]: profileReducer,
  [reportpageContext]: reportReducer,
  [learningContext]: learningReducer,
  [globalContext]: globalReducer,
})
```

My saga:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    authPageSaga(),
    profilePageSaga(),
    learningSaga(),
    reportPageSaga()
  ])
}
```

**UPDATE**

After getting some help. I was connected to sagas and now I can persist data to it. But I'm very confusing this step.

`loadState` function return me an object localStorage `auth` like this:

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1lbWJlcjJAZ21haWwuY29tIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIxMjM0NTYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzEzOTE1NTMsImV4cCI6MTUzMTM5NTE1M30.75vj-YCeJtxuXjOqzisVRkFVMKe7fcpHLByWQ-x_frE",
    "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "member2@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Mr. Pierre",
        "lastName": "Schneider",
        "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stalewine/128.jpg",
        "address": "4706 Kessler Turnpike Apt. 800 Rautown Borders",
        "phone": "021-292-7337",
        "division": "Front End Group 1",
        "password": "123456",
        "role": "member"
}
```

And next how we can load that `auth` object and save to `initState` in `authReducer`

authReducer:

```
const initState = {
  token: '',
  user: {},
  error: false
}

function authReducer(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCEEDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.userResponse
      }
    case AUTH_LOGOUT_SUCCEEDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.userResponse
      }
    case AUTH_LOGIN_FAILED:
    case AUTH_LOGOUT_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        user: {}
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I was tried do this:

```
const persistedState = loadState();

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  persistedState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
)

store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
  saveState({
    access_token: store.getState().authpage.token,
    user: store.getState().authpage.user,
  })
}, 1000));
```

But in `authReducer`. It did not return me state that I expected.

It showed me an error:

`Unexpected keys "access_token", "user" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "authpage", "profilepage", "flashmessage", "reportpage", "learning", "global". Unexpected keys will be ignored.`

What did I wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that `loadState` is synchronous and key names are the same you simply pass `persistedState` as the second argument

```
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  persistedState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
)
```

[Docs](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/createstore)

> 2. `[preloadedState]` (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify
>      it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to
>      restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced reducer
>      with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape
>      as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything
>      that your reducer can understand.

**UPD**
Since the structure of persistent value is not the same as the structure of your store you need to prepare `persistedState` value before passing it to `createStore`

```
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {
    [authpageContext]: {
      token: persistedState.access_token,
      user: persistedState.user
    }
  },
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
)
```

Or simply use the same name when persisting the state to avoid additional conversion.

```
store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
  saveState({
    [authpageContext]: store.getState()[authpageContext]
  })
}, 1000));
```